# Make two divs align in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First of all, I've looked at all of the suggested links. I'm new to CSS and don't know how to incorporate it into this.

I want to have the h1 header that says "Basics" align with the tab that says "Site Basics." They already sort of do, but they are not directly aligned with each other.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
        <title>Site Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div class="site-wrapper">
            <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
                <div class="cover-container">
                    <div class="masthead clearfix">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <h3 class="masthead-brand">Site Title</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="support_container">
                        <div id="left_nav" class="h_navbar">
                            <h1 class="h1_title">Basics</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div id="right_nav" class="h_navbar">
                            <ul id="">
                                <li class="h_tab" id="tab_basics"><a href="#" id="nav_href">Site Basics</a></li>
                                <li class="h_tab" id="tab_comparison"><a href="#" id="nav_href">Comparision</a></li>
                                <li class="h_tab" id="tab_whats_new"><a href="#" id="nav_href">What's New</a></li>
                                <li class="h_tab" id="tab_faq"><a href="#" id="nav_href">FAQ</a></li>
                                <li class="h_tab" id="tab_issues"><a href="#" id="nav_href">Known Issues</a></li>
                                <li class="h_tab" id="tab_bug"><a href="#" id="nav_href">Report a Bug</a></li>
                                <li class="h_tab" id="tab_email"><a href="#" id="nav_href">Email Us</a><li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Custom CSS:

```
/* Links */
a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/** Container **/
.support_container
{
    background-color:white; 
    padding:30px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-radius:7px;
}

/* Custom default button */
.btn-default,
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none; /* Prevent inheritence from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}


/*
 * Base structure
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}
body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

/* Extra markup and styles for table-esque vertical and horizontal centering */
.site-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* For at least Firefox */
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.site-wrapper-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.cover-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* Padding for spacing */
.inner {
  padding: 30px;
}


/*
 * Header
 */
.masthead-brand {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.masthead-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.masthead-nav > li + li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff; /* IE8 proofing */
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a:hover,
.masthead-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #a9a9a9;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}
.masthead-nav > .active > a,
.masthead-nav > .active > a:hover,
.masthead-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .masthead-nav {
    float: right;
  }
}

.h_p { 
    color:black; 
    text-shadow:none;
}

#nav_href{ 
color:black; 
text-shadow:none;
}

.h_tab { 
    display:block; 
    border-top: 1px solid #eee; 
    padding: 11px 25px 9px 0; 
    text-decoration:none;
}

.h1_title { 
    color:black; 
    text-shadow:none;
}

#right_nav { 
    margin: 30px -30px 30px 0; 
    width:190px; 
}

/*
 * Cover
 */
.cover {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*
 * Footer
 */

.mastfoot {
  color: #999; /* IE8 proofing */
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}


/*
 * Affix and center
 */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Pull out the header and footer */
  .masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  .mastfoot {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Handle the widths */
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%; /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 700px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsbin.com/vugekikana/3/edit

I just had to modify the `body` css not to be `text-align:center` and added this:

```
#left_nav{ display:inline-block; margin-top:10px; }
#right_nav{ display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; }
```

Comment: thanks, I actually meant that the "Basics" be right next to the Site Basics, not on top of it :p

Comment: that's better now, how can i get it so the "basics" is on the opposite side of where it is now?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want them aligned to the left then remove `text-align:center;` from your body and add `padding:0;` to the ul element of the nav in your stylesheet.

Alternatively if you want the nav in the center then add `display: inline;` to `nav_href` so use:

```
#nav_href {
   display: inline;
}
```